# Iterating over subsets of any size

Tags: c++, algorithm

I can iterate over the subsets of size 1

```
for( int a = 0; a < size; a++ ) {
```

or subsets of size 2

```
for( int a1 = 0; a1 < size; a1++ ) {
    for( int a2 = a1+1; a2 < size; a2++ ) {
```

or 3

```
for( int a1 = 0; a1 < size; a1++ ) {
for( int a2 = a1+1; a2 < size; a2++ ) {
   for( int a3 = a2+1; a3 < size; a3++ ) {
```

But how to do this for subsets of size n?

This does the job, based on an answer by Adam Rosenfield

```
void iterate(int *a, int i, int size, int n)
{
 int start = 0;
 if( i > 0 ) start = a[i-1]+1;
 for(a[i] = start; a[i] < n; a[i]++) {
  if(i == n-1) {
      // a is the array of indices of size n
      for( int k = 0; k < size; k++ ) {
          printf("%d ",a[k]);
      }
      printf("\n");
  }
        else
            iterate(a, i+1, size, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose you would add a few more comments to your answer? I'm clearly being slow but I'm not really following it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
void iterate(int *a, int i, int size, int n)
{
    for(a[i] = 0; a[i] < size; a[i]++)
    {
        if(i == n-1)
            DoStuff(a, n);  // a is the array of indices of size n
        else
            iterate(a, i+1, size, n);
    }
}
...
// Equivalent to 4 nested for loops
int a[4];
iterate(a, 0, size, 4);
```

Comment: This is interesting.  However a[i] > a[j] where i>j is not enforced

Comment: But if I add this:

 int start = 0;
 if( i > 0 ) start = a[i-1];
 for(a[i] = start; a[i] < size; a[i]++)

Comment: Oops!  Should be 

 int start = 0;
 if( i > 0 ) start = a[i-1]+1;
 for(a[i] = start; a[i] < size; a[i]++)

Comment: One more change needed.  The for loop maximum should be n, rather than size.  With these changes, the algorithm works in production code and passes unit tests!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I used for a similar problem. It does not use recursion; rather, it uses a vector of indexes.

```
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class MultiForVar {
std::vector<T> _begin, _end, _vars;
inline int dim(){return _vars.size();}
public:
MultiForVar(std::vector<T> begin, std::vector<T> end) : _begin(begin), _end(end), _vars(_begin)
{
  assert(begin.size() == end.size() and "Starting and ending vector<T> not the same size!" );
}
MultiForVar& operator ++()
{
  ++_vars[dim()-1];
  for(int d = dim()-1; d > 0; --d)
  {
    if( _vars[d] >= _end[d] )
    {
      _vars[d] = _begin[d];
      ++_vars[d-1];
    }
  }
  return *this;
}
bool done()
{
  /*for(int d = 0; d < dim(); ++d)
    if( _vars[d] < _end[d] )
      return false;
  return true;*/
  return (_vars[0] >= _end[0]);
}
T operator[](int d)
{
  return _vars.at(d);
}
int numDimensions(){
  return dim();
}
std::vector<T>& getRaw(){
  return _vars;
}
```

};

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, another way to do it is to use bit-wise operators:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1<<size; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
       if(i & 1<<j) printf("%d ", a[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something the constructs the powerset of the original set. It's been a while since I've written that, but the psuedocode looks like

```
Powerset(a, size)
{
   if(size == 0) return emptyset

   subseta = Powerset(a, size-1) // Powerset of everything except last element
   subsetb = appendToAll(a[size-1], subseta) // appends the last element to every set in subseta
   return union(subseta, subsetb)
}
```