# How to find permutation of k in a given length?

Tags: language-agnostic, permutation

How can I find the permutations of k in a given length?

For example:

The word `cat` has 3 letters: How can I find all the permutations of 2 in the word `cat`.
Result should be: `ac`, `at`, `ca`, `ac`, etc...

---

This is not a homework problem.
Any language could be used but more preferable: C/C++ or C#. 
I know how to create the recursion for size LENGTH but not for a custom size.

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: Nope... Not homework problem and any language could be used but more preferable: C/C++ or C#.

Comment: I know how to create the recursion for size LENGHT but not for a custom size.

Comment: Do the partitions need to be lexicographic?

Comment: Can the characters be repeated? I assume they can be...

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663949/how-do-i-get-all-permutations-of-xpy-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Comment: 127704 is not dupe (it is about combinations, not permutations), and 1663949 does not seem to deal with repeated characters, though I would expect this would have been asked before.

Comment: @Moron: Who said characters can be repeated? There's no `aa` in the "results should be".

Comment: @KennyTM: No. That is not what I meant. Since he seems to want english words, banana is valid input and so you should not duplicate aa in the output now (which the standard algorithm will).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one in C#, which should work even with repeated characters. For example on "banana" for permutations of length 2 it gives:

> ba bn ab aa an nb na nn

The basic idea is to fix the first character, then form all permutations of length k-1, then prepend the character to those k-1 length permutations. To deal with duplicate characters, we keep track of the count left (i.e the ones which can be used for sub-permutations).

Not exemplary code, but should give you the idea. (If you find bugs, let me know and I can edit).

```
static List<string> Permutations(Dictionary<char, int> input, int length) {
    List<string> permutations = new List<string>();

    List<char> chars = new List<char>(input.Keys);

    // Base case.
    if (length == 0) {
        permutations.Add(string.Empty);
        return permutations;
    }

    foreach (char c in chars) {

        // There are instances of this character left to use.
        if (input[c] > 0) {

            // Use one instance up.
            input[c]--;

            // Find sub-permutations of length length -1.
            List<string> subpermutations = Permutations(input, length - 1);

            // Give back the instance.
            input[c]++;

            foreach (string s in subpermutations) {

                // Prepend the character to be the first character.
                permutations.Add(s.Insert(0,new string(c,1)));

            }
        }
    }

    return permutations;
}
```

And here is the full program I have, to use it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StackOverflow {

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            List<string> p = Permutations("abracadabra", 3);
            foreach (string s in p) {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }

        static List<string> Permutations(string s, int length) {
            Dictionary<char, int> input = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            foreach (char c in s) {
                if (input.ContainsKey(c)) {
                    input[c]++;
                } else {
                    input[c] = 1;
                }
            }
            return Permutations(input, length);
        }

        static List<string> Permutations(Dictionary<char, int> input, 
                                                          int length) {
            List<string> permutations = new List<string>();

            List<char> chars = new List<char>(input.Keys);
            if (length == 0) {
                permutations.Add(string.Empty);
                return permutations;
            }

            foreach (char c in chars) {
                if (input[c] > 0) {
                    input[c]--;
                    List<string> subpermutations = Permutations(input, 
                                                                length - 1);
                    input[c]++;

                    foreach (string s in subpermutations) {
                        permutations.Add(s.Insert(0,new string(c,1)));
                    }
                }
            }

            return permutations;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Y_Y: Glad it helped! It was fun to revisit this one after a long time.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with the recursive solution and passing an extra parameter (depth) so that the recursive function returns immediately for depth > n.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient, but it works:

```
public class permutation
{
    public static List<string> getPermutations(int n, string word)
    {
        List<string> tmpPermutation = new List<string>();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(word) || n <= 0)
        {
            tmpPermutation.Add("");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                string tmpWord = word.Remove(i, 1);
                foreach (var item in getPermutations(n - 1, tmpWord))
                {
                    tmpPermutation.Add(word[i] + item);
                }
            }
        }
        return tmpPermutation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void Prem (char *str, int k, int length) {
    if (k == length-1){
         printf("%s\n",str);
         return;
    } else {
        for (int i = k ; i < length; ++i) {
            char t = str[k];
            str[k] = str[i];
            str[i] = t;
            Prem(str,k+1,length);
            t = str[k];
            str[k] = str[i];
            str[i] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, this problem can be solved by combinadics too, as on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinadic/, there are reference implementations there too.

I have used the Java solution (http://docs.google.com/Doc?id=ddd8c4hm_5fkdr3b/) myself for generating all possible triples from a sequence of numbers, this should be no different.

I lack the wherewithal to explain the math behind it, but as I understand this is the least complex way to iterate over all possible nCr (i.e. 3C2 for your cat example) choices within a collection.

Answer (score 0):

First find the possible subsets of your array. You can do this in
a recursive way it was discussed in [Iterating over subsets of any size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683241/iterating-over-subsets-of-any-size)

Second calculate the permutations of every subset with the STL-Algorithm
[next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/)

I haven't implemented it but i think it should work.